# subprocess.Popen sets size and location of the external executed programme?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to execute an external programme from python via subprocess.Popen. I am wondering whether it is possible to set size and location of the window for the external programme that is executed via the command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume Windows for such a question?

You may specify the window to be minimized or maximized, using the [`startupinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) parameter of popen.

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
si.wShowWindow = 3   # SW_MAXIMIZE
```

See the [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation for the list of values. AFAIK there is no named constant for them in the subprocess module.

The other window-related parameters of `STARTUPINFO` are not supported by popen at the moment. Most notably, none of `dwX`, `dwY`, `dwXSize` or `dwYSize` are supported.

As an alternative, you can check whether your implementation has a windows-specific extension, such as ActiveState's [`win32process.CreateProcess`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32process__CreateProcess_meth.html)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to execute an external programme via win32process.CreateProcess with size and location parameters?

Comment: @Yanagiba> As I have no Windows box around, I'd rather not post some code I cannot test, but [this page has examples](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/8489/win32process.CreateProcess). For instance, Example #7 sets the window size, among many other parameters.